# FullCalendar adjusts timezone when set to local but not on Europe/Athens

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetime, fullcalendar

Hi i m using `FullCalendar 2.1.1` and i face an issue with timezone.
The application is being developed with `Yii framework` and when i set the timezone to Europe/Athens

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Athens'
```

timezone is set to GMT 0000 it neglects the setting while if i set

```
'timezone' => 'local'
```

timezone is set to GMT 0200 as expected.
The problem is that the dates that are used in the appare based on Europe/Athens zone, so i don't think it is safe to rely on local time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your machine is not aware of 'Europe/Athens' time zone so you have to define it.

How to do this ?

refer to here :

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/

> Timezone string (like "America/Chicago")
>
> Use this mode if you store timezone information for your events and
>   you want them displayed in a timezone that can be customized.

```
{ title: "event1", start: "2013-10-20T02:00:00+09:00" }
//                                     ^        ^
//                     will display as 2:00     |
//                                              |
//             timezone offset will always be +09:00
```

If you want to fetch TZ settings , usually it is done in server side , but using node.js + moment.js will be easier to for you , please check this :

http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/

Comment: my issue is not with fetching events, but with selecting timeslots and sending data back on the backend, where when using local setting it sends data back at GMT +0200 while with Europe/Athens it submits data with GMT 0000

Comment: @nikolas yes i know what your issue is , but i was showing you how to define a timezone.

Comment: ok so taking into consideration the daylight changes also, is there some way, i could get the current offset when timezone is set to Europe/Athens? and so that i could add this offset to the fullcalendar

Comment: @nikolas do you mean that the time offset for Athens changes over seasons ?

Comment: during daylight saving period when time is moving +1 hours ahead the gmt is 0300 while during winter time it is gmt +0200 isn't this correct?

Comment: no, i didn't manage to do it with a clean solution. it got even more complex :(
i set all times to utc and when i got back to load events, they returned to localtime!!

Comment: i have somehow settle the management, apart from the initial timeslot choice, where in the backend i substract from the post timestamp the Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("Z", 0)*36; which actually gets me the difference in seconds from the utc

Comment: have you checked how to use moment.js or not ?

Comment: i have, i just haven't figured out over here 
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_method/ how i will parse start to moment with Europe/Athens timezone..i think it is only possible by adding the extra moment-timezone library

Comment: i added on the extention as well the moment-timezone-with-data and modified start to
var starttz = moment.tz(start, 'Europe/Athens');
and it returned the correct result!!